# Limit to the number of connections to a single SQS Queue

Tags: amazon-sqs

Is there a limit to the number of producers and consumers on a single AWS SQS queue?

I'm being told that a queue will only support a maximum of 50 connections from producers and consumers total.  That being said I can not find any documentation that supports that claim.

Comment: Where are you seeing a 50 limit?

Comment: The only places I have found a reference to a limit of 50 is the AWS SDK limits the concurrent connection to 50 and there is a 50 principal limit for the queue policy.  I'm not able to find anything that indicates a number of connection limit.

Comment: I’m not familiar with that connection limit. Can you link to the documentation on that? The policy limit I’m aware of, but I don’t think that’s necessarily a limiter for the question you’re asking, unless the potential producers are in different accounts.

Comment: @BradJ There are no permanent "connections" to an Amazon SQS queue. Each API call is independent. Are you facing any specific problems?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein that's true, but with long polling there are longer lived connections, especially compared to most other API calls in AWS.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-quotas.html @JasonWadsworth this is where the 50 principle limit is listed at the bottom.  I've not encountered an actual issue, but I was told in an architectural review that having more than 50 producers and consumer (services) for a single SQS queue would be a problem.  That said, the reviewer was not able to produce any documentation to this claim and I haven't been able to find documentation myself.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-throughput-horizontal-scaling-and-batching.html

Note
As you scale horizontally, you must ensure that your Amazon SQS client has enough connections or threads to support the number of concurrent message producers and consumers that send requests and receive responses. For example, by default, instances of the AWS SDK for Java AmazonSQSClient class maintain at most 50 connections to Amazon SQS. To create additional concurrent producers and consumers, you must adjust the maximum number of allowable producer and consumer threads on an AmazonSQSClientBuilder object, for example:

```
final AmazonSQS sqsClient = AmazonSQSClientBuilder.standard()
        .withClientConfiguration(new ClientConfiguration()
                .withMaxConnections(producerCount + consumerCount))
        .build();
```

For AmazonSQSAsyncClient, you also must make sure that enough threads are available.

Comment: Sorry, but this does not answer my question.  I'm looking for a queue limitation, not the client limitations.  I was told that if I had more than 50 producers and consumers accessing a queue, it would start to fail.  This quite honestly doesn't make sense to me since that would mean every implementation of SQS would fail.  As you found the default for the client is 50 threads, which means if I have a consumer and a producer hitting a single SQS queue, it would fail under load...as I would be over the 50 connection limit on the queue.